# Extract the number of specific characters from a text file using awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file that looks like this. I would like to extract the total number of “A” and “E” characters.

```
>pr1
FSVSQNNPAE
>pr2
MAKERAHSQ
>pr3
RRRDKINNWIVQL
```

I would like to get the output like this

```
>pr1 
Total number of A - 1 
Total number of E - 1   

>pr2
Total number of A – 2
Total number of E - 1

>pr3
Total number of A – 0
Total number of E – 0
```

How can I do this with awk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way. When found a line beginning with `>`, read next one, save it in `str` variable and count number of substitution for each letter.

```
awk '
    $1 ~ /^>/ {
        getline str
        num_a = gsub( /A/, "", str )
        num_e = gsub( /E/, "", str )
        printf "%s\nTotal number of A - %d\nTotal number of E - %d\n\n", $0, num_a, num_e
    }
' infile
```

Output:

```
>pr1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Total number of A - 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Total number of E - 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

>pr2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Total number of A - 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Total number of E - 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

>pr3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Total number of A - 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Total number of E - 0
```

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**: This will work by changing the `FS` ([field seperator](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_23.html#SEC26)) on the fly:

```
{
  if ($0 ~ /^>/)
    printf("\n%s\n", $0);
  else
  {
    FS="A"
    nl = $0;
    $0 = nl;
    print "Total number of A - ", NF-1; 

    FS="E"
    $0 = nl;
    print "Total number of E - ", NF-1;
  }
}
```

gives:

```
>pr1
Total number of A -  1
Total number of E -  1

>pr2
Total number of A -  2
Total number of E -  1

>pr3
Total number of A -  0
Total number of E -  0
```

---

*Previous solution*:

```
{
  if ($1 ~ /^>/)
    printf("\n%s\n", $0)
  else
  {
    print "total number of A - ", gsub(/A/,"A")
    print "total number of E - ", gsub(/E/,"E")
  }
}
```

similar to @Birei's

Comment: What is the thought behind changing FS?

Comment: @KarlNordström Working solution posted .. I *knew* this was possible with the `FS` .. just had to get the sequence right.

Comment: @KarlNordström Sorry about all the messages, I thought you were the OP .. apologies.

Comment: Wasn't my meaning to give that impression. I was just curios.

Comment: +1 for a not so common (working) solution modifying FS out of the BEGIN block.